# Laravel return String of Id column

Tags: php, laravel, object

I have id column type (CHAR 7) of table PEOPLE like:

```
id       name               address
-------+------------------+---------
0010014  MUZZACHIODI FELIX  SAN MARTIN
```

My controller:

```
$people= People::find($id);
```

View return INTEGER:

```
{{ $people->id }} return 10014
```

How keep string id? I tried {!! $people->id !!} or (string)$people->id

Expected output:

```
0010014
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell Laravel, through your model, that the [primary key is not an integer](http://seanbachelder.me/2016/03/06/non-integer-primary-key-in-laravel.html):

```
class People extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false; // <---------
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) your `id` as a string like so

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'string',
];
```

but I'd recommend keeping your record `id` an auto incrementing int, and adding something like a `person_id` that would contain your string id as you might run into issues managing the model with a cast id.